# I would like to detect a custom shape using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I would like to detect the shape below, I have tried the following methods:

1) Training a cascade using `opencv_traincascade` and creating the positive images using `opencv_createsamples` - no success, lot's of false positives, the object does not have many features.

2) Tried doing ellipse detection, again lots of false positives as there's many ellipses in the scene. Also, it didn't give a solid detection as it's not a perfect ellipse.

3) Tried colour detection, gave good results but the object has multiple colours, ranging from green, red, blue and yellow, hence colour cannot be used for detection. Also, it varies due to illumination.

I was wondering whether I could train a classifier using the edges or some other way of customly defining a shape and detecting that in the scene.

[Results using canny edge detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssL74.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try contour extraction and `cv::matchShapes`? I found chamfer matching to be quite good, but it needs some task specific optimizations to handle the necessary cases like object rotation, object scale and perspective distortions. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#double%20matchShapes(InputArray%20contour1,%20InputArray%20contour2,%20int%20method,%20double%20parameter)

Comment: I'd check out the [Nature Conservancy](https://www.kaggle.com/c/the-nature-conservancy-fisheries-monitoring) Kaggle competition discussion boards. There's a lot of discussion regarding similar problems.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for that, I have tried contour extraction but didn't try `cv::matchShapes` will give that a try. 

@Tchotchke Awesome, thanks for pointing me in that direction - will check out the discussion(s).

Comment: @Micka In regards to using `cv::matchShapes`, in order to get real-time results over the whole image is the idea to use a sliding window approach at different scales and use the coefficients that are returned to distinguish between matches and no matches? If not, then how do you extract the bounding box that encompasses a object that has a good match.

Comment: you should extract contours (see cv::findContours) after edge detection or thresholding and compare shapes (each image contour against your target contour). If you can, try to eliminate as many contours as possible in advance (by color or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this. After that you have the edge image:

1. Use `findContours()` to obtain the separated contours.
2. Plot every contours on black image and use `convexHull` in order to have a shape with that contour.
3. Build an edge template of your shape and apply `convexHull` on it: this will be your template to find in every new image.
4. For every new image, compute `Normalized Cross Correlation` and find the coordinates with max Correlation.

This method has a strong assumption: the shape you're looking for is not varying its rotation or its scale. If you want to be invariant to rotation and scale you should apply another method to compare Template and the Imgae (for example a template matching that is rotation and scaling invariant, such as this: http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2013/papers/Korman_FasT-Match_Fast_Affine_2013_CVPR_paper.pdf )